# I partition the data with a range partition strategy according to the Initial of stock code, which leads to an uneven partition result

Tags: database, kdb, dolphindb

I partition the data with  a range partition strategy according to the Initial of stock code, which leads to an uneven partition result. How to solve the uneven problem?

I need to do partition on the stock’s bid data according to two dimensions: date and stock code. If I only do a range partition according to the Initial of stock code, as there are few stocks start with “U, V, X，Y，Z”, the data distribution may be uneven. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

data distribution doesn't need to be perfectly spread... what is the spread that you have with doing that... do you have 'hot spots' that could be considered overly concentrated? or only a few partitions that are empty?

Answer (score 0):

In order to facilitate partitioning according to the distribution of data, DolphinDB provides the function cutPoints(X, N, [freq]). Here X is an array, N refers to how many groups need to be generated, and freq is an equal-length array of X, where each element corresponds to the frequency of the element in X. The function returns an array with (N + 1) elements, representing N groups, so that the data in X is evenly distributed in these N groups.
In the following example, you need to partition the stock quote data according to the two dimensions of date and stock ticks. If you simply divide the range by the first letter of the stock, it is easy to cause uneven data distribution, because a very small number of stock ticks start with U, V, X, Y, Z and other letters. Here we use the cutPoints function to divide the stock ticks into 128 partitions based on the data on the day of 2007.08.01, and each partition contains the same number of records on this day:

```py
t = ploadText(WORK_DIR+"/TAQ20070801.csv")
t=select count(*) as ct from t where date=2007.08.01 group by sym
bolbuckets = cutPoints(t.symbol, 128, t.ct)
dateDomain = database("", VALUE, 2017.07.01..2018.06.30)
symDomain = database("", RANGE, buckets)
stockDB = database("dfs://stockDBTest", COMPO, [dateDomain, symDomain])
```